# Remove or replace add to cart button on a product in catalog by condition programmatically

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

Preconditions:

- Magento 2 clean installation with Luma.
- We shouldn't use templates.
- The replacement needs to create a popup form related to product data to send and save it to my grid.

I'm searching for a way to replace the add to cart button from a product in the Magento catalog with my condition. I found the only way to hide the button with JS and set my button instead, but it's not a "clean" way and I know that we can do it more correctly, probably with an observer or plugin.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the product from Adding to cart you can use below code:
app/code/Vendor/Extension/etc/events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="prevent_add_to_cart" instance="Vendor\Extension\Observer\PreventAddToCart" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Create a observer file under:
app/code/Vendor/Extension/Observer/PreventAddToCart.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;


class PreventAddToCart implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $messageManager;
    protected $redirect;
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
        ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        Session $checkoutSession,
        RedirectInterface $redirect
    ) {
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        // Your custom logic to prevent adding to cart
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
   }
}
```

Also to Hide Add to cart button use plugin code as below:

Create a di.xml file - Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="hideaddtocart" type="Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Hideaddtocart" sortOrder="32"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then, create Vendor\Module\Plugin\Hideaddtocart.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Plugin;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class Hideaddtocart
{
    public function afterIsSaleable(Product $product)
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

I hope this answer finds helpful.

Comment: I know this approach and it's helpful but only in case we need to remove the button, what about replace?

Comment: Replace the button with what ?

Comment: Let's say replace the add to cart button with a custom HTML code - let it be just a simple <button></button>.